# TypeScript2 - how to get strings into 2d strings array

Tags: angular7, typescript2.0

So I am using angular 7 and have a csv file I couldn't take care of so I've code my first typescript 2 script but failed... I want to have an array of column and row correspondant do the csv file in TypeScript 2

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as fs from 'fs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProduitsService {
  public productsArray: [][];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

    let file = fs.readFileSync('../assets/produits.csv', 'utf8');
    let lines = file.split("/\r?\n/");
    for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        this.productsArray[i] = lines[i].split(",")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you got?

Comment: Script is failing at which point?

Answer (score 0):

1.) your products array is not initialized,
initialize with

`public productsArray: [][]=[]`

2.) your multidimensional array type might need to be explicitly declared depending on typescript version ie

`public productsArray: string[][];`